# Way to Connect to all ec2-instances one by one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python

Is there any way through which I can connect to all ec2-instances one by one through Python script to extract some server information from there. Please note that all ec2-instances lies behind a bastion host. Using shell script I can do that but how about python. Is there any specific library?

Comment: More information might be helpful, like whats the end result? You want to run commands on these servers? Why not use ansible?

Comment: @Levi I need to extract some information from database.yml files residing in each ec2 instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can benefit from EC2 inventory script provided by Ansible - [click](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py)
It will allow you to to connect to all ec2-instances, one by one (in `serial: 1` mode)